# Get the content of a PHP file based on set template name

Tags: php

First, this is only PHP and not Wordpress (to avoid confusion), but I want to do this like wordpress.

So my question is, Is there a way to get the content of a PHP file based on the template name? For example this is the PHP file I want to get the content

```
FILE.php

<?php
// Template Name: HOMEPAGE
?>

<H1> HELLO WORLD </H1>
```

Now I want to get the content of `FILE.php` which is "`hello world`" by calling the Template Name "`HOMEPAGE`".

This function is similar to wordpress if you are familiar with it, thats what I want to do. Im not sure if this is possible in PHP without using Wordpress.

Edit: I know how to get contents like using `include`, but by using `include` I will need to specify the `filename.php` not the template name, so that's not what Im looking for.

Comment: This is certainly possibly in PHP. It sounds like you want to open a file and dump the contents somewhere like an `include`. Look into opening and reading files, that's a great start.

Answer (score 0):

Some where you need to associate the template name with the file name and then look up the file name based on the template name.  Wordpress tends to store every thing in database tables but for purposes of simplicity, I'm just going to hard code the values in an array

```
$convert_file_names=array("template_name"=>"file_name.php", "HOMEPAGE"=>"hello_world.php");
include($convert_file_names["HOMEPAGE"]);
```

You might want to avoid spaces in your file names.

Comment: Where did the file `hello_world.php` came from? assuming I will add your code in the `index.php` file to call the `file_name.php` with template name `HOMEPAGE`

Comment: You stated that you wanted to ". . . get the content of a PHP file based on the template name".  I'm assuming that you have those PHP files stored somewhere.  The hello_world.php file in my example is just an example.  You can replace that with whatever file you want to call.